# Jquery tengo 2 document on click, y solo funciona si quito 1

Tags: jquery

Hola tengo dos funciones, una que elimina filas, y otra que edita, esto lo llevo a cabo con `$(document).on('click', function...);`

**Función 1:**

```
$(document).unbind('click').on("click",".btr",function(){
    alert('click');
    if( $("#articulos tr").length > 2 )
    {
        var parent = $(this).parents().parents().get(0);
        $(parent).remove();
    }//end if });
```

**función 2:**

```
$(document).unbind('click').on('click', '.bte', function(){
    //extraigo el index
    index = $('.bte').index(this);
    //extraigo el nombre con index
    nombre = $('.articulo').eq(index).val();
});
```

EL PROBLEMA:. 
si quito uno funciona el otro correctamente, pero si tengo ambos no me funciona alguno.

Comment: Ojo que el cierre del primer `.on( ... )` está comentado en el código que publicaste. Igual supongo que sólo es un error al copiarlo a la pregunta

Answer (score 3):

El problema principal es que estás utilizando

```
$(document).unbind('click').on("click",  ...
```

para ambos eventos, por lo que se está llamando a `.unbind()` en ambos casos asociado a `$(document)`. Es decir, al llamar al segundo `unbind()` se está eliminando el evento que recién se asoció.

En cambio, podrías llamar a `.unbind` sólo para la clase específica al que asociamos el evento. Uno para la clase `btr`:

```
$(".btr").unbind('click').on("click",function(){
    // Código del evento 
});
```

Y otro para la clase `bte`:

```
$(".bte").unbind('click').on("click",function(){
    // Código del evento 
});
```